# Tasselled Cap coefficients for Advanced Land Imager

Tags: remote-sensing

It seems that there are co-efficient values; wetness, greenness and brightness, available for all the Landsat series and MODIS but I can't find anything relating to ALI.

Does anyone know the values or where they can be found?

Answer (score 2):

There is a USGS technical note with an approximation of the ALI coefficients for brightness, greenness and wetness.

[Yamamoto, K.H., and M.P. Finn (2012) Approximating Tasseled Cap Values to Evaluate Brightness, Greenness, and Wetness for the Advanced Land Imager (ALI). USGS Scientific Investigations Report 2012–5057.](http://cegis.usgs.gov/soil_moisture/pdf/sir12-5057.pdf)

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but the TC values vary for each image should they not remain a constant for all? Similar to the bottom of page 5 here: http://web.pdx.edu/~jduh/courses/Archive/geog481w07/Students/Marcello_TasselledCap.pdf